# Hover image display description

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to display description on hover image but when hover on image then all image display description.
I have the following code....

```
    <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
    <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <div style="display:none;" class="de"> Nunc ornare adipiscing orci eu consectetur. Ut justo libero, porttitor ac elementum luctus, bland..

    <img alt="Based on 2 reviews." src="catalog/view/theme/kid/stars1-4.png"/>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $this('.image').hover(function() {
    // mouseOver function
        $('.de').show();
    }, function() {
    // mouseOut function
    $('.de').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: use tool tip or set alt tag on image

Comment: check out the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/some/dir" title="Your description" alt="alternate text"/>
```

Is the correct way of adding an description. Mind you, I'm not quite sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: This might be semantically correct but it's not very useful for the end user. And I'm not even sure it's semantically correct — I've always seen `alt` preferred to `title`, if only because it's mandatory.

Comment: I can see why you would use the alt tag for descriptions as it's probably one of the most misused tags of all. However, the alt tag's original function is to provide an alternate text if the image file is missing / couldn't be loaded.

Comment: Alt is not a tag. On further research, I do agree that `alt` is for alternate text and not for clarifying text. Also, `alt` is mandatory for images, so it should be in this code.

Comment: Well, sorry, I meant attribute. But you're right regarding it being mandatory of course.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your div is display none, and your image is inside it. So it won't be displayed.

```
<div style="display:none;" class="de"> Nunc ornare adipiscing orci eu consectetur. Ut justo libero, porttitor ac elementum luctus, bland..
</div>
<img alt="Based on 2 reviews." src="catalog/view/theme/kid/stars1-4.png"/>
```

Do you have an example of how your html looks when there are more images? Here's the javascript I came up with, with your current html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('img').hover(function() {
    // mouseOver function
        $(this).prev('.de').show();
    }, function() {
    // mouseOut function
        $(this).prev('.de').hide();
    });
</script>​
```

I've used the selector "img". But you might want to use a class, and maybe use a delegate (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BvLPY/6/

happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**updated**

use `.next()` in this script:

just find the next div to the hovering `.image` div

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.image').hover(function() {
    // mouseOver function
        $(this).next('.de').show();
    }, function() {
    // mouseOut function
        $(this).next('.de').hide();
    });​
});
</script>
```

find this in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/SufeL/**

Comment: oops did not read the question well. just updating the answer.

Comment: i think need to check the closest div to image